# How can I get to the bottom of a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I want to open my Google Sheets and go automatically to the bottom/last line entered as there are over 2000 lines.

I have entered the below text in: tools > script editor, as seen in another post however, it's not working in either sheet that I am not the owner and that I am the owner.

Can anyone help me understand why?

```
function onOpen(e) {
    var spreadsheet = e.source;
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    var row = 5;
    while (true) {
        var range = sheet.getRange("B" + row);
        if (!range.getValue()) {
            sheet.setActiveRange(range);
            return;
        }
        row++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your spreadsheet opens, you want to go automatically to the cell in Column B containing the last line of content.

Your script attempts to do this incrementally, however there are a couple of flaws:

- `!range.getValue()`

  - tests for no value. This is wrong, it should be `range.getValue()`
- `return;`

  - By including this, you stop the row number from incrementing, so the script goes no further than row 5.
- you start at row 5 and move 1 row at a time = very slow progress. A modified script got to row #138 before the script was terminated due to having exceeded the maximum execution time.

---

The key aspects of this answer are:

- `Bvals`

  - gets all the values in Column B.
- `Bvals.filter(String).length`

  - returns the number of records.
- `sheet.getRange(Blast,2);`

  - sets the range for the last cell *in Column B*
- `activecell.activate();`

  - activate that cell and takes the cursor to the last cell *in Column B*.

An alternative to determining the last row is `getlastRow()`. This [returns the position of the last row that has content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow). However, there is no certainty that the "last row of content" is in Column B; it might be in some other column.

---

```
function onOpen() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var Bvals = ss.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var Blast = Bvals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log(Blast)

  var activecell = sheet.getRange(Blast,2);
  //Logger.log(activecell.getA1Notation());

  activecell.activate();
}
```